# Populating Collections using Spring Data Projections

Tags: spring-data, jpql, projection

I'm struggling trying to figure out how to use nested projects / populating the many side. I have a User entity that has a `ManyToMany` relationship with Brand. I've created the following Projection interfaces...

```
interface UserView {
    @Value("#{target.id}")
    fun getId(): Long
    fun getFirstName(): String
    fun getLastName(): String
    fun getBrands(): MutableSet<BrandView>
}

interface BrandView {
    fun getId(): Long
    fun getName(): String
    fun getDescription(): String
}
```

In my repository, I have the following `@Query`

```
@Query("select u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, b.id, b.name, b.description from User u left join u.brands b where u.id = :id")
fun findByIdUsingProjectionDto(@Param("id") id: Long): UserView
```

The SQL that gets generated is correct and will return appropriate data, however, even though the `UserView` is populated with data, `getBrands()` returns null. I'm unsure how to get the query to also populate the brands collection.